# How do I stop MS Graph component popping up during Interop?

Tags: c#, interop, ms-office

When using Office Interop in C#, if you insert a chart object into a MS Word document, the Grap application loads up very briefly and then goes away. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I have tried setting the Visible property of the application instance to false to no effect.

EDIT: The Visible property does take effect when used against Word when interopping, and it **does not** pop up. I would expect there is a similar way to do this for MS Graph.

Answer (score 1):

This is common behaviour for a lot of component hosted in an executable binary. The host application will startup and then do the job. I don't know if there is a surefire way to prevent that since you have no control over the component nor over the process until the application is started and is responding.

A hack I tried in the past (for something totally unrelated) was starting a process and constantly detecting if its main windows was created. As soon as it was created, I was hiding it. You could do this with the main module of the faulty application and hope it will be fast enough to hide the window before the user notices. Then you instanciate your component; the component will *usually* recycle an existing process, hopefuly the one with the hidden main window.

I can't garentee you this will work in your situation, but it's worth a try it the issue is that important, or if you don't find a better way of course.